# How can I convent the SQL query into relational algebra?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-algebra

Assume there are two dataset:

```
User(id, name, phone)

Friend(id, fid)
```

fid is the id-user of the friend of the id-user

To find the name of all friends of id=123 I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = (SELECT fid FROM friend WHERE id = 123)
```

I think of this relational algebra:

```
PROJECT name (SELECT uid =123 (Friend * User))
```

Any suggestion to improve/correct it?

Comment: Added an answer for the first part, can you explain what you are trying to achieve for the second part starting project.... so i can help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM user u
INNER JOIN Friend f ON u.ud = f.fid
WHERE f.id = 123
```

Comment: Is that sub-query cannot change to relational algebra ??

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve for the second part starting project.... so i can help with that

Comment: I am not sure whether my answer(the relational algebra statement)  is correct so asking for help on this statement.

Comment: What is the out put you are trying to achieve from the algebra ?